# How to insert an entry to a table only if it does not exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My table looks like this  on sql server

```
wordId     word      
----------------
1214       pen           
1215       men    
1216       cat
```

WordId and word is being passed with the stored procedure and,I need to check on my stored procedure if the wordId already exists on the table or not, and only if the wordId doesn't exists I need to execute the insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Your_ProcName(@wordId INT,@word VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Your_Table WHERE wordId = @wordId)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Your_Table (wordid, word)
        SELECT @wordId, @word
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Values already Exists'
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a unique index on `wordid`:

```
create unique index unq_t_wordid on t(wordid);
```

This will protect the data and ensure that no duplicates are inserted.

Second, in any particular `insert`, you can check as you insert:

```
insert into t (wordid, word)
    select wordid, word
    from (. . .) x
    where not exists (select 1 from t where t.wordid = x.wordid);
```

Of course, ultimately, I recommend that you define `wordid` as an identity column, but you may have some other reason for actually inserting the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Your_ProcName(@wordId INT,@word VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @nCount int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON
     Select @nCount = Count(*) from Your_Table WHERE wordId = @wordId
   BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage1 varchar(4000)    
    IF (@numRec > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorMessage1 = 'ERROR: A wordId is already exists.'
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage1, 16, 1)
        END
        IF @numRec = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO Your_Table (wordid, word)
            SELECT @wordId, @word
        COMMIT

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            @ErrorMessage1 AS 'ERROR_MESSAGE'
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage1, 16, 1)
    END CATCH




END
GO
```